# Scroll a page section using another section

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web-deployment

I'm trying to make a page section that you can scroll on with another section. 

Example: https://www.getrepeat.io
[image]

[image]

As you can see, "GIVE YOUR RETURNING" section is being scrolled on by "THE RIGHT PRODUCT" section. But also, while "GIVE YOUR RETURNING" section is being scrolled on by the other section, "GIVE YOUR RETURNING" section is also moving moving together with the other section. Right now, I only know how to do this while "GIVE YOUR RETURNING" section is not moving together with the other section.
How do I achieve this section effect like in the example website? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you think of the simplest way, then you can do it by adding `border-radius` and `box-shadow` to each sections

Comment: @buzz how is this gonna help? I’m afraid you‘re gonna need javascript for this kind of action.

Comment: @Psi yes...I only showed the design perspective...OP needs JS for Intersection Observer to check which section is in the viewport

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using pure CSS.
Try this:

```css
     ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        position: sticky;
        overflow: hidden;
        top: 0;
        width: fit-content;
     }
     li {
        float: left;
        border-right: 1px solid white;
     }
     li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 8px;
        background-color: #ede7e2;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;         
     }
     li:last-child {
        border-right: none;
     }
     div {
        padding:5px;
        margin-top:5px;
        background-color:white;
        height:1000px;
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sticky Nav</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
     <li><a href = "#home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href = "#news">News</a></li>
     <li><a href = "#contact">Contact</a></li>
     <li><a href = "#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div>
     <p>Adding demo text to check fixed menu.</p>
     <p>Adding demo text to check fixed menu.</p>
     <p>Adding demo text to check fixed menu.</p>
     <p>Adding demo text to check fixed menu.</p>
     <p>Adding demo text to check fixed menu.</p>
     <p>Adding demo text to check fixed menu.</p>
     <p>Adding demo text to check fixed menu.</p>
     <p>Adding demo text to check fixed menu.</p>
     <p>Adding demo text to check fixed menu.</p>
     <p>Adding demo text to check fixed menu.</p>
     <p>Adding demo text to check fixed menu.</p>
     <p>Adding demo text to check fixed menu.</p>
     <p>Adding demo text to check fixed menu.</p>
     <p>Adding demo text to check fixed menu.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sadly, this is not what i'm looking for. This snippet shows a sticky header with scrolling items under it  and the header element not acting as a scrollable section, also the top section should be scrollable on by another section while moving up.